# excel formula to find the month from the filename

Tags: excel

anyone know how I can pull out just the month from this filename:

G:\Personal\Day Books\2021-22\03. Jun-21\01. Accounts\Management Accounts - Jun-21 - v2.xlsm

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We need  a lot more information , where is this written? where do you want the out to be?

Comment: Is it the current file? Then you can access the filename with `=CELL("filename")` (after it has been saved).

Comment: oh, its just in a cell in the workbook. There are a lot of other formula's dependent on the month. I'm just trying to save time having to manually change the month every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array (CSE-Control+Shift+Enter) formula in C1 is as below returning "Jun"

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(FALSE,IFERROR(FIND({"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"},A1,1),"")="",0),"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")
```

--- OR ----

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(FALSE,ISERROR(FIND({"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"},A1,1)),0),"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")
```

[image]

Note that the formula matches the first instance only. So, if the file name is `"G:\Personal\Day Books\2021-22\03. May-21\01. Accounts\Management Accounts - Jun-21 - v2.xlsm"` then it will return May and not Jun. If you want to match the second instance then you can use nested find to start the outer find from a different position, say from "Accounts".

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is there not a way to use Right to start from the end of the filename? Reason being there are a number of other files which don't have Accounts in for instance but which has the date at the end. For example. \tracker - Jun-21.xlsm

Comment: To use those functions we need to know length of the string or position of the month within the string.. If the string is same every time except the month then it is possible with [MID function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-mid-function)

Comment: understood thanks Naresh, I'll start with using the MID function and play around until I have something. Thanks for your suggestion!